# What is wrong with my light

Tags: wiring, light

I have two ceiling light fixtures that just will not work.

I checked the incoming power in the ceiling. Its fine.

I did a continuity test on the wires/socket and they are fine.

As a test I connected the wires to a simple plug and plugged the light into the wall. Nothing.

I tried a continuity test across the ptongs of the plug, with the light bulb in place. Nothing open circuit.Yes I double checked that the bulb is ok in another lamp.

There is a separate ground wire and a third insulated wire. Continuity test with the third insulated wire and the socket showed an open circuit, so I am sure I was using the right wires.

So what am I missing?

Thanks

R

Comment: Most likely, there's a broken wire somewhere. Without information, how could we say more?

Comment: There isn't any history here, did they ever work?  Are they new?  What kind of lights are they?  What is the voltage from the wiring in the ceiling?  The more information, the better someone can help.

Comment: Can you link the product?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: When I hear , I am sure I used the right wires I add 50$ to a service call.  You connected the fixtures to a known working outlet and nothing ??? Incoming hot in ceiling?  not enough wires in use how about a photo.

Comment: Since no new info I vote to close.

Comment: Time to close no response after this long.